# Can anyone identify this European ?naval uniform from photograph and likely date (belle époque)?)

Tags: military, identification, naval, uniform

[image] Possibly late 1800s, early 1900s. Almost certainly from the UK. Epaulettes may indicate Naval?

Comment: Lieutenant in the Royal Navy, with (I suppose) full dress uniform of roughly 1900.  Maybe the photo was taken after a medal-awarding ceremony?  If you know his name you could look him up in the London Gazette

Comment: The medal might be the "East and West Africa Medal", which was awarded between 1887 and 1900.

Comment: Agree with @kimchilover - though a very similar ribbon was also used for the Ashanti Medal (1874), and the Africa General Service Medal (1902 onwards). The National Archives have digitised medal rolls for the Naval elements of all of these (ADM 171/37, /45-48, and /56), but digging through them all would be quite time-consuming.

Comment: The Naval General Service Medal (awarded from 1915 on) also has a similar ribbon.

Comment: @kimchilover I think (based on [the WP list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_campaign_medals)) there may have been two Ashanti Medals, perhaps with different spelling - Ashantee vs Ashanti? 1874 had a very similar ribbon to EWAM and AGSM, 1901 was different.

Comment: @Andrew  I just noticed the Ashantee/Ashanti difference, too. I retract my earlier comment.

Answer (score 4):

This gentleman, indeed, appears to be a Lieutenant in the Royal Navy in the full dress uniform worn in accordance with the regulations of 1891 as published [here](https://ia801202.us.archive.org/4/items/royal_navy_uniform_regulation_1891/royal_navy_uniform_regulation_1891.pdf) in 1893.  The absence of a pip above the anchor on his epaulets indicate that he has less than 8 years seniority as do the two plain stripes on his sleeve. These two items are illustrated below from the referenced publication. The appearance of his collar, given the lighting of the photograph gives some pause, however a close up look shows the gold lace is indeed as it should be against a white background, but is merely darkened in shadow with only the fold at the lower corner showing bright.  I believe his decoration is either the [Africa General Service Medal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa_General_Service_Medal) or the [East and West Africa Medal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_and_West_Africa_Medal) as those two seem to fit the general time frame.  The [Ashantee Medal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashantee_Medal), as mentioned in comments, would have been far too early (1873-1874) for a junior Lieutenant in this uniform.

[image]

[image]